# String to double?

Tags: haskell

So for my assignment I have to create a couple functions (new to Haskell).
I can do the following quite easily

```
data Shape
    = Circle Double -- radius
    | Square Double -- length
    | Rectangle Double Double --length and width
    deriving (Show)

showShape :: Shape -> String
showShape (Circle r) = "circle of radius " ++ show r
showShape (Square l) = "square of length " ++ show l
showShape (Rectangle l w) = "rectangle of length " ++ show l ++ " and width " ++ show w

area :: Shape -> String
area (Circle r) = 
    "Circle of radius " ++ show r ++ " has an area of " ++ show (pi * r * r)
```

Except my assignment specifically wants me to use

```
area :: Shape -> Double
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: `pi * r * r` have `Double` type. What is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you do :

```
data Shape
    = Circle Double -- radius
    | Square Double -- length
    | Rectangle Double Double --length and width
    deriving (Show)

showShape :: Shape -> String
showShape (Circle r) = "circle of radius " ++ show r
showShape (Square l) = "square of length " ++ show l
showShape (Rectangle l w) = "rectangle of length " ++ show l ++ " and width " ++ show w

area :: Shape -> Double
area (Circle r) = (pi * r * r)
```

it works for me.

I think your problem is that you try to do two things in the same function :

1. Calculate the area
2. Return a nice string info with the area

Your function, with the `area :: Shape -> Double` should only calculate the area.